# INSERT OR IGNORE conversion sqlite to mariadb

Tags: sqlite, mariadb

I'm trying to convert my SQlite code to Mariadb but i'm stuck with a query for a crossed table between two another tables

The purpose of the table is to add ID from the other table but only if they don't exists

I have two tables

Table COMPUTERS
ID(primary) / NETBIOS(unique) / IP / SOFTWARE_STAT / COPY_STAT / AV_STAT
ex : 1 PC1  192.168.1.1  KO KO 0

Table SOFTWARES
ID(primary) / NAME(unique)
ex : 1 ADOBE

And the cross table

Table INSTALL
ID (primary)/ COMPUTER_ID / SOFTWARE_ID / FAIL
1    1            1         0

My SQLITE code below is working

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO INSTALL (COMPUTER_ID,SOFTWARE_ID) 
SELECT 
(SELECT ID FROM COMPUTERS WHERE IP = '192.168.1.1'),
(SELECT ID FROM SOFTWARES WHERE NOM = 'ADOBE') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 
COMPUTER_ID,SOFTWARE_ID FROM INSTALL 
WHERE 
COMPUTER_ID = (SELECT ID FROM COMPUTERS WHERE IP = '192.168.1.1') 
AND 
SOFTWARE_ID = (SELECT ID FROM SOFTWARES WHERE NOM = 'ADOBE')
)
```

I've tried that

```
INSERT INTO INSTALL (COMPUTER_ID,SOFTWARE_ID) 
SELECT 
(SELECT RowID FROM COMPUTERS  WHERE IP='192.168.1.1'),
(SELECT RowID FROM SOFTWARES  WHERE NOM='ADOBE') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT COMPUTER_ID,SOFTWARE_ID FROM INSTALL 
WHERE 
COMPUTER_ID = (SELECT RowID FROM COMPUTERS  WHERE IP='192.168.1.1') 
AND 
SOFTWARE_ID = (SELECT RowID FROM SOFTWARES  WHERE NOM='ADOBE'));
```

Without success

Someone have an idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the schema for each table.

Comment: Ok I write it down

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT OR IGNORE` --> `INSERT IGNORE`

However, you have a redundancy:  (1) `IGNORE`, and (2) `NOT EXISTS`.  That is, you both verify that it is not a dup and you ignore errors if it is.

Otherwise, the Sqlite code should work as is in MariaDB. What went wrong? Did you get an error?

MariaDB has no `RowID`.

Comment: Oh thank you, it work with INSERT IGNORE !
But Im not at work at the moment and ive trred with Mysql no MariaDB